# Are "Markdown to Docx using Pandoc" questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

I wanted to make sure whether this site would be an appropriate form to ask a question regarding Pandoc.

Specifically, I'm **using Pandoc to convert Markdown to a Word DOCX file** so would the main site this be the proper location to ask about it?

The reason I ask is that LaTeX is not involved (or at least not directly involved) but at the same time, I do see Pandoc questions here and feel that this user base may have the answer I need.

Comment: If no TeX is involved, then it's off-topic here. *But* there are so many `pandoc` and Markdown users on this site that you might get an answer in chat.

Comment: I think it would as well make sense to post the question where it belongs ([SO]) and give posting a link in our chat a try. We don't like people advertising in chat a lot, but in this case, it makes sense (at least to me).

Comment: A real question can be migrated (if necessary), properly answered, properly reference (also the answers of their own). You can get a permalink to a chat posting, but since the SE network is also about making a good archive, sorting by votes etc. ... I think a real question is better, no matter where it appears in the first place.

Comment: If you haven't tried it already you might find https://groups.google.com/d/forum/pandoc-discuss useful too.

Comment: @AndrewCashner Sounds like the only possible answer :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If no TeX is involved, then it's off-topic here. Stack Overflow is the right place to ask the question.

All the same, many users on this site use `pandoc` and Markdown, and have lots of experience converting document formats. So if you don't get an answer to your SO question you might ask in the chat room here.

Comment: thanks, will do!

Comment: I suggest that Super User, rather than Stack Overflow. it is the use of a program (pandoc) rather than the construction of a program (eg in C++ or perl)